# Interaction between pitch accent and mi-prefixation

Tags: honorifics, pitch-accent, rendaku

I'm interested in the ways in which words that can be prefixed with *mi*- might vary in accent. For instance, both *mi-kokoro* and *mi-gokoro* are attested (albeit rare and highly archaic), but *mi-kokoro* is L-H-H-H whereas *mi-gokoro* is L-H-L-L. My questions are as follows:

- Are there other pairs that show this sort of alternation (i.e., deaccenting without sequential voicing vs. accent-preserving with sequential voicing)?
- In general, *o*-prefixation is deaccenting. Is this the case with *o-kokoro* (again, rare but attested), in which it would become L-H-H-H?
- In exceptional cases, we see nonstandard forms like *o-mi-gokoro*. Do these become L-H-H-H-H again?

Comment: Re: your first bullet, a (maybe?) opposing example: 山川(やまがわ{LHHH}) vs 山川(やまかわ{LHLL}). Obviously not related to mi-, but just in case you were considering a more general phenomenon.

Comment: おこころ is pronounced accentless, although こころ is accented at the last mora. *おみごころ doesn't exist but there is おおみごころ{LHHHLL}/おおみこころ{LHHHLL}, where おおみ is the original form of お-. An example of お+み is [おみあし](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%BF%E3%81%82%E3%81%97), which interestingly has two accents おみあし{LHHH}/おみあし{LHLL}.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that o-mi-gokoro "doesn't exist" in the sense that it's a contested form. It does appear in a 1904 edition of the Japan Weekly Mail (https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/5H8zAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA434&dq=migokoro+christian), in which it is discussed as dubious/pleonastic. In any case, I am interested in whether this form, even if objectionable, would take heiban accent. (Native speakers are generally able to imagine what possible [distinct from actual, and distinct from impossible] words might sound like, what regular morphology they might take, etc.)

Comment: @TadhgÓConaill The preview resolution as I can see is pitiful and the context is curtailed, but I guess what they mean is "O migokoro, o mitama, o mimegumi(?)", where the first parts stand for the interjection "oh", isn't it?

Comment: No, that is not the case. If you read the footnote, you'll see that it's clearly analogized to other multiply honorificated forms.